# PHP Sum Children in Array

Tags: php, arrays

Hey I have an array where I would like to sum the values of the first-level children at various levels of the array.

```
<?php
$group = Array('Electronics' => Array(
                   '6 - Cameras & Supplies' => Array(
                'Cameras' => Array(
                    'Camcorders' => Array (
                        'Action Camcorders' => Array (
                            'total_ty_yest_sales' => 70.83,
                            'total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales' => 401.59,
                            'east_ty_yest_sales' => 65.20
                        ),
                        'Standard Camcorders' => Array (
                            'total_ty_yest_sales' => 96.09,
                            'total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales' => 96.09,
                            'east_ty_yest_sales' => 68.21
                        ),
                        'Surveillance' => Array(
                            'total_ty_yest_sales' => 84.00,
                            'total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales' => 84.00,
                            'east_ty_yest_sales' => 26.00
                        )
                    ),
                    'subCameras' => Array (
                        'Big Zoom' => Array(
                            'total_ty_yest_sales' => 31.66,
                            'total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales' => 13.68,
                            'east_ty_yest_sales' => 1.47
                        ),
                        'Pegged Cameras' => Array(
                            'total_ty_yest_sales' => 13.50,
                            'total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales' => 5.50,
                            'east_ty_yest_sales' => 5.00
                        ),
                        'Point-N-Shoot' => Array(
                            'total_ty_yest_sales' => 46.61,
                            'total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales' => 10.35,
                            'east_ty_yest_sales' => 4.06
                        ),
                        'Rugged Cameras' => Array(
                            'total_ty_yest_sales' => 87.04,
                            'total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales' => 87.04,
                            'east_ty_yest_sales' => 65.20
                        ),
                        'SLR' => Array(
                            'total_ty_yest_sales' => 50.19,
                            'total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales' => 9.40,
                            'east_ty_yest_sales' => 1.37
                        )
                    )
            )   )   
        ));
        $totalSum = 0;
        echo "<table>\n
                <thead></thead>\n
                <tbody>\n";

        foreach($group as $gmm => $acctg_dept_nbrs) {
            echo "<tr class=\"header\">\n
                    <td>" . $gmm . "</td>\n";

            foreach ($acctg_dept_nbrs as $acctg_dept_nbr => $dept_catg_grp_descs) {
                echo "<tr class=\"header\">\n
                        <td style=\"padding-left: 1em;\">" . $acctg_dept_nbr . "</td>\n";
                            echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">SUM</td>\n";
                            echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">SUM</td>\n";
                            echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">SUM</td>\n";
                $total_acctg_dept_nbr = 0;
                foreach($dept_catg_grp_descs as $dept_catg_grp_desc => $dept_category_descs) {
                    echo "<tr class=\"header\">\n
                            <td style=\"padding-left: 2em;\">" . $dept_catg_grp_desc . "</td>\n";
                            echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">SUM</td>\n";
                            echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">SUM</td>\n";
                            echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">SUM</td>\n";
                    $total_dept_catg_grp_desc = 0;
                    foreach($dept_category_descs as $dept_category_desc => $dept_subcatg_descs) {
                        echo "<tr class=\"header\">\n
                                <td style=\"padding-left: 3em;\">" . $dept_category_desc . "</td>\n";
                                echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">SUM</td>\n";
                                echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">SUM</td>\n";
                                echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">SUM</td>\n";

                        foreach($dept_subcatg_descs as $dept_subcatg_desc => $values) {
                            echo "<tr>\n
                                    <td style=\"padding-left: 4em;\">" . $dept_subcatg_desc . "</td>\n";

                            $sum = $values['total_ty_yest_sales'];
                            echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">".$sum."</td>\n";
                            $sum = $values['total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales'];
                            echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">".$sum."</td>\n";
                            $sum = $values['east_ty_yest_sales'];
                            echo "<td style=\"width:100px;\">".$sum."</td>\n";

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

?>
```

I want to replace the "SUM"s in the output with the sum of the values of next level of indention.

Comment: Have you looked at [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum)?

Comment: I have, but I do not quite understand how to apply it in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reference the values at each level because the values are only held at the lowest level of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient thing to do, but you can create a function that calculates the sum of an array recursively:

```
function array_sum_recursive($array)
{
    $sum = 0;

    array_walk_recursive($array, function($item) use (&$sum) {
        $sum += $item;
    });

    return $sum;
}
```